# Looping through IDs for with API

Tags: python, api

I am trying to bulk download movie information from The Movie Database. The preferred method mentioned on their website is to loop through movie IDs from 1 until the most recent movie ID. When I pull individual movies using their ID, I get the entire set of information. However, when I pull it into a loop, I receive an error 34, resource cannot be found. For my example, I picked specifically a movie ID that I have grabbed individual (Skyfall, 37724), which returns the resource cannot be found error.

```
import requests

dataset = []

for i in range(37724, 37725):
    url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/x?api_key=*****&language=en-US'
    movieurl = url[:35] + str(i) + url[36:]
    payload = "{}"
    response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload)
    data = response.json()
    dataset.append(data)
    print(movieurl)     

dataset
```

[ANSWERED] 1) Is there a reason for why the loop cannot pull the information? Is this a programming question or specific to the API?

2) Is the way my code set up the best to pull the information and store it in bulk? My ultimate goal is to create a CSV file with the data.

Comment: You are requesting your data from `url` instead of `movieurl` -- could that be your issue?

Comment: That's it! Wow! Do you have thoughts on my second question?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your request uses url, while your actual url is in the movieurl variable.
2. To write your data to csv, I would recommend the python csv DictWriter, as your data are dicts (response.json() produces a dict).
3. BONUS: If you want to format a string, use the string.format method:

   ```
   url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{id}?api_key=*****&language=en-US'.format(id=i)
   ```

   this is much more robust.

The working, improved version of your code, with writing to csv would be:

```
import csv

import requests

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile)
    for i in range(37724, 37725):
        url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{id}?api_key=*****&language=en-US'.format(id=i)
        payload = "{}"
        response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload)
        writer.writerow(response.json())
```

Comment: Thanks! However, this returns the following error:`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-42c94a1ea853> in <module>()
      4 
      5 with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
----> 6     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile)
      7     for i in range(37724, 37726):
      8         url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{id}?api_key=a792ae6c41aa660a503fb1c835a3daa7&language=en-US'.format(id=i)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fieldnames'`